# UseEffect change is not instant ? But it still render somehow

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-effect

I wanted to login not from function but from useState statement change, if login and fetch status is true, then User can get API. The problem that I noticed were

1. Those changes wasn't instant
2. Even tho it's not instant (via console log it was still false) but the return, if login == true, still render.

Question is , what is the best practice for this situation ? Is it possible not to creating new function / only using useEffect?

The problem is in useState, setLoginStatus , setFetchStatus , that doesnt change statement from FALSE to TRUE (via console log) but it does render  that requires the statement to be TRUE. If it changes those statement to be true it will run the useEffect, right ?

```
      export default function TabOneScreen ({navigation}) {
        const [loginStatus,setLoginStatus] = useState(false)
        const [fetchStatus,setFetchStatus] = useState(false)


       function Login(){
        ////// this is the login button
        console.log('stating login dan fetch')  
        setLoginStatus(true)
        setFetchStatus(true)
        LoginSucess()
      }
    
      useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(fetchStatus,loginStatus)
        if (loginStatus == true && fetchStatus == true){
          console.log(login sucess , fetching API)
          gettingAPI()
        }
      },[fetchStatus])

    if(loginStatus==true) {
    return(
      <View style={styles.loadingContainer}>
        <View style={styles.etcContainer}>
        {loadingView == false ? 
          <View><Text style={{color:'#008080'}}>Fetching...{loginStatus}</Text></View> : 
          <View><Text style={{color:'#008080'}}>If fetching persist more than 10s, contact operator</Text></View>}
        </View>
        <LoadingScreen/>
        <View style={styles.etcContainer}>
        {loadingView == false ? 
          <View></View> : 
          <View></View>}
        </View>
      </View>
    )
    } else{
    <View style={styles.loginButton1}>
        <TouchableOpacity 
            onPress={()=>Login()}
            color="#aaa"
            style = {styles.buttonLogin}
        >
        <View style={styles.loginButton2}>
        <Text  style={[{color:'white' , fontWeight: 'bold'},gS.fontSize24]}> Login </Text>
        </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      }
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget **return** inside **else**?

Comment: the problem is not in the view , I just shortened my code cause its too long, the problem is in the useState, setLoginStatus , setFetchStatus , that doesnt change statement from FALSE to TRUE (via console log) but it does render <View> that requires the statement to be TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it would be easier of u do it like this :

```
export default function TabOneScreen() {
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(false);
  const [fetchStatus, setFetchStatus] = useState(false);

  function Login() {
    setLoginStatus(true);
    setFetchStatus(true);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(fetchStatus, loginStatus);
    if (loginStatus && fetchStatus) {
      setTimeout(()=>{
         alert("login sucess ,fetching API"); 
          setLoginStatus(false);
          setFetchStatus(false);
      }, 1000);
    }
  }, [fetchStatus, loginStatus]);
  
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        {loginStatus?
        <View>
          <Text style={{color:'#008080'}}>Fetching...{loginStatus}</Text>
        </View> :
          <Button
            onPress={()=>Login()}
            title="Press Me"
          />}
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

[Expo](https://snack.expo.io/@b3hr4d/button-basics)

Comment: hey thank you , im using setTimeout right now its 6000 ms just in case i failed getting API

Comment: i think u should use .catch for reset form too , i did use setTimeout for simulate fetching api.
example: `fetch('https://example.com/user', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: ...,
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(result => {
  console.log('Success:', result);
}).catch(error => {
          console.error('Error:', error);
          setLoginStatus(false);
          setFetchStatus(false);
})`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the same code, sorry its a bug idk if its from expo or react. The useEffect re-render as intended